# How to save checkbox value in kivy, so when i reopen the app the checkbox value still the same and not be resetted

Tags: python, checkbox, kivy, kivy-language

i'm trying to make like a checklist table application in kivy, using hundreds of checkbox. I wanna know how to save the checkbox. For example, if i activate the checkbox, when i close and reopen the app, i wanted the checkbox still active. Because i'm using hundred of checkbox, its impossible to use hundreds of object property, can you help me? also, is there other way to make checklist table like this without having to type too many checkbox?

this is the image example
[image: this is the image example]

```
# the test.py
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

class FirstScreen(Screen):
    pass

class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return kv

kv = Builder.load_file("test.kv")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

```
#test.kv
<FirstScreen>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 13
        Label:
            text:'ROOM'
        Button:
            text:'Deposit'
        Button:
            text:'JAN'
        Button:
            text:'FEB'
        Button:
            text:'MAR'
        Button:
            text:'APR'
        Button:
            text:'MEI'
        Button:
            text:'JUN'
        Button:
            text:'JUL'
        Button:
            text:'SEP'
        Button:
            text:'OKT'
        Button:
            text:'NOV'
        Button:
            text:'DES'
        Button:
            text:'1'
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        Button:
            text:'2'
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        Button:
            text:'3'
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        Button:
            text:'4'
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        Button:
            text:'5A'
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        Button:
            text:'5B'
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        Button:
            text:'6'
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        Button:
            text:'7'
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        Button:
            text:'8'
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        Button:
            text:'9'
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        Button:
            text:'10'
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        Button:
            text:'11'
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        Button:
            text:'12'
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        Button:
            text:'13'
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
        CheckBox:
```

Comment: Instead of typing everything out in kv like this, write some python code do dynamically construct the table.

Comment: And for the saving, you'll want to store the current state in a file, update the file whenever it changes, and load it from the file when the application is started.

Comment: and how could i do that?

Comment: Have a look at [Application configuration documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.app.html#application-configuration).